# Is it "ok" to add the final keyword to an inherited/overridden method?

Tags: java, android, inheritance

In Android i create an abstract class that extends `View` (an Android class to which i have no access).
The abstract class overrides the Views

```
@Override
protected final void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if(conditions) return;        

    // child classes should only draw if this class gives the ok
    subDraw(canvas);
}

protected abstract void subDraw(Canvas canvas);
```

however i added the final keyword here.

The point is, i create an abstract method that the subclasses are supposed to use instead of the onDraw. So i prevent the onDraw from being overridden any further and it works.

I know there are designs to make this better, however this works like a charm without a lot of change. My question is more in general if doing the above has unwanted side effects at runtime or other issues ?!

Comment: yes, if that' the behavior you want and you aware of what your are doing

Comment: it is exactly what i want

Comment: Side effect is that it makes your subclasses harder to  (unit-)test. This is because you cannot mock this method. And therefore you cannot separate the subclasses behavior from this classes behavior. There are ways to solve this, but using the "favour composition over inheritance" approach whithin your application design would be best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, technically it's a clean solution. If you are absolutely sure there is no situation when someone might want to change any logic inside this particular method you could do that.

Also, you have to remember that this method has to contain the least logic possible, as it can not be altered by any descendant. If you think this method will grow in size (without using delegates) avoid finalizing it.